# jquery - mouseover effect should/musst stay on click until another element get clicked

Tags: jquery, click, mouseover, mouseout

Helly guys,

[first here the jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XvsQa/1/)

and here my problem. I have 3 path's. Every path shall/should have an mouseover effect (change the fill). That works for me. 2 of the 3 path's shall/should be clickable and on a click the mouseover effect shall/should stay until I click on another (clickable) path. So the new clicked path get the effect and before clicked path loose it.

The problem ist that the click effect get removed by the mouseout function!!!

So in shorts words. The click effect should stay until i click another path AND only one path can have the clicked effect at the same time.

I hope you gyus understand my problem. Look at jsfiddle so you can better understand.

Greets.

ps: the function that on a click an div box appears with a text about the path is the second thing i need, but this works great, sou you can ignore it ;)

Comment: Iam messing around with this problem since 3 full days. this is so frustating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XvsQa/13/).

An important note is that if you are calling a collection of elements and you have to give each the same behavior on a certain event you have to use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or .delegate() for older jQuery versions).

Comment: Dude you are my Hero. Im messing around since 3 days with this, cause i am a JS noob. Thank you so very much. Maybe I have little bit to adjust the code for me but you make it possible. Thank you!

Comment: This is strange. If I put your JS code in my local html file it didnt work anyway. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I'm sure you did not forget to add the jQuery Library on your code and you placed the codes inside a <script> tag. So I am not sure why is it happening.

Comment: jQuery Library is added (1.7.1) and the code is of course inside a <script> tag. I was so happy an now this. I try to get it run.

Comment: So strange. It want not work. Can you pls maybe make a local file with jquery and all and look if it works?

Comment: I tried doing it on my local and it appears in the browser as expected.

Comment: I got the error. The first JS code was in a seperate <script> tag and the second JS code for the popup div was also in a seperate <script> tag. Now i put both JS codes in one <script> tag and it works.